# add rows to jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, addition

I'm doing an exercice about java swing, now it's time to add rows from a database to the jTable, I know that the method to do this is "addRow()" but netBeans doesn't suggest it to my and underline the line as a mistake.

Is necesary to import something before, or does someone know what I'm doing bad?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[addRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) is an instance method of `DefaultTableModel` rather than `JTable`. Set the model for the `JTable` and then add to it:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] { "Column 1", "Column 2"});
model.addRow(new String[] { "foo", "bar" });
```